# Jquery Radio button submit value onclick

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, radio-button

I am currently in process of developing my website: users profile section-selecting profile image; where in my html structure is:

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <img src="a.jpg"><br>
   <input type="radio" name="profile" value="a" >
 </td>
 <td>
   <img src="b.jpg"><br>
   <input type="radio" name="profile" value="b" >
 </td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is to submit the value onchange using jquery ajax however I have tried several approach and tests like:

```
$("input:radio[name='profile']").click(function(){
 alert($(this).val());
});
```

and

```
$("input:radio[name='profile']").change(function(){
 alert($(this).val());
});
```

FYI: I know the ajax part I just dont know how will I approach the onchange/onclick part..please guide me to start

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/RsRDK/

Comment: is the html part dynamically created? like using script/ajax... is the code added in dom ready handler

Comment: @Arun Yes it is dynamically created

Comment: If it's created dynamically, why not add the event handlers dynamically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it is created dynamically, use event delegation

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="profile"]:radio', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```